# Javascript / Jquery detect 403 on iframe

Tags: javascript, jquery

If have an iframe which connects and displays the data of a local api

My problem is that sometimes the iframe will get a 403 error.

How can I detect the 403 so I can display an alternetive message or page?

Comment: have to tried anything yet?

Comment: Instead of setting the url of the frame in the `src` attribute, you should "test" the url by sending a `HEAD` request to the url with Ajax and in case of success, you set the `src`attribute of your iframe. If you receive an error, you display your message.

Comment: Is the iframe own your domain?

Comment: Yes, iframe is in the same domain

Comment: Did you try JQuery load method [link](http://api.jquery.com/load/) for your Iframe?? It may help you to get to know that Iframe is completely loaded or not

Comment: You could try setting the display attribute of the iframe to none and using [IFrame contentDocument Property](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_frame_contentdocument.asp) check to change the display attribute if the body got the rigth content... This is more of a workaround than a solution and depending on the server response page the body will look different, so check for things the API returns.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the property [IFrame contentDocument](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_frame_contentdocument.asp)

This is an example:

```
<html>
 <body>
   <iframe id="myframe" src="http:/www.stackoverflow.com/"></iframe>
   <p>Click the button to change the background color of the document contained in the iframe.</p>
   <p id="demo"></p>
   <button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>
   <script>
       function myFunction() {
          var x = document.getElementById("myframe");
          var y = (x.contentWindow || x.contentDocument);
          if (y.document)y = y.document;
             y.body.style.backgroundColor = "red";
             y.body.getElementsByTagName("h1")[0].innerHTML = "Done";
            //h1 because for me, the 404 error was displayed as <h1> tag.
            //but like this you got access to the "DOM"
       }
   </script>
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I need to detect a 403 not 404

Comment: @Satch3000 the idea is that using the access to the DOM, you check for an specific tag that the API will have in its response... maybe a script tag in the <head> or something like that... other wise you'll have to bring the content using ajax and insert it in your page DOM.